# Upper bound of algorithm with flooring

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, recursion

Would much appreciate someone explaining how they managed to get to the upper bound of this algorithm.
$$T(n) = 2T(\lfloor \sqrt n\rfloor) + ln (n)$$
$$T(1) = 0$$
Solution is given as:
$$T(n) = O(logn*log(log(n)))$$

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/2789/755

Comment: I'm aware of the general method, it's the flooring with a square root that's throwing me for a loop however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a number is of the form $n = 2^{2^k}$ then you never encounter the floor as you open up the recursion, and then there is no problem. If you're interested in a general upper bound, you can prove by induction that $T(n)$ is monotone in $n$: if $n \leq m$ then $T(n) \leq T(m)$. Now given $n$, find some $m \leq n^2$ which is of the form $2^{2^k}$, and then
$$ T(n) \leq T(m) = O(\log m \log\log m) = O(\log n \log\log n). $$